# i am getting error in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

hi i have frame this query and i encountered a error
like this.i have tried many but no result .i have modified query then its showing   another error.
   
      Failed to prepare the following query
   
    Error preparing SQL statement.

```
SQL error #1:Syntax error: Encountered "MONTH" at line 4, column 46.





SELECT distinct productline as StringFact,orderdate,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(orderdate) between 
(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(orderdate,INTERVAL -12 MONTH),'%Y-m%-01'))
AND (DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(orderdate,INTERVAL -11 MONTH),'%Y-m%-01')) THEN BUY END)          AS      PREVYEAR,

SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(orderdate) between 
 (DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 0 MONTH),'%Y-m%-01'))
 AND (DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(orderdate,INTERVAL 0 MONTH),'%Y-m%-01')) THEN BUY END) AS        CURRENTMONTH,

SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(orderdate) between 
(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 MONTH),'%Y-m%-01'))
AND (DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(orderdate,INTERVAL -1 MONTH),'%Y-m%-01')) THEN BUY END) AS    LASTMONTH

  from (select orderdate,productline as StringFact,
  sum(QUANTITYINSTOCK + BUYPRICE) as BUY,
  sum(QUANTITYORDERED * PRICEEACH) as MSRP

   from customers, orders, orderdetails, products
  where customers.customernumber = orders.customernumber
   and orders.ordernumber = orderdetails.ordernumber
  and orderdetails.productcode = products.productcode
  Group By productline,orderdate
 )
 Group By productline,orderdate
```

Comment: The error message is not what i think it should be, but if i am not wrong mysql requires each subquery aliased.

So can you put an alias to the sub-query and try executing again ?

Comment: i have tried again its showing same error only...is there any way can do this..

Comment: I think '%Y-%m%-01' should be '%Y-%m-01', there is no %m%, [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Comment: Are you really sure that is the error ? Because you did not select productline or APC from sub-query but you use them in outer query.

Comment: sry sir instead of APC just add Buy from subquery

Comment: i have changed %Y-%m%-01' to '%Y-%m-01 again its showing same error?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not what i think it should be.

What is your mysql version ?

1) You should give an alias to sub-query
2) Another problem is, you selected "product_line" at outer query, but product_line is selected as "StringFact" at sub-query, that's why the outer_query will not be able to select product_line.

I changed your query as follows and it executes with no problem.

Here is the sqlfiddle for your query http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26218/6

```
SELECT distinct productline as StringFact,orderdate,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(orderdate) between 
(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(orderdate,INTERVAL -12 MONTH),'%Y-m%-01'))
AND (DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(orderdate,INTERVAL -11 MONTH),'%Y-m%-01')) THEN BUY END)              AS      PREVYEAR,

SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(orderdate) between 
 (DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 0 MONTH),'%Y-m%-01'))
 AND (DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(orderdate,INTERVAL 0 MONTH),'%Y-m%-01')) THEN BUY END) AS            CURRENTMONTH,

SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(orderdate) between 
(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 MONTH),'%Y-m%-01'))
AND (DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(orderdate,INTERVAL -1 MONTH),'%Y-m%-01')) THEN BUY END) AS    LASTMONTH

  from (select orderdate,productline , # removed as StringFact
  sum(QUANTITYINSTOCK + BUYPRICE) as BUY,
  sum(QUANTITYORDERED * PRICEEACH) as MSRP

   from customers, orders, orderdetails, products
  where customers.customernumber = orders.customernumber
   and orders.ordernumber = orderdetails.ordernumber
  and orderdetails.productcode = products.productcode
  Group By productline,orderdate
 ) t # You need to give an alias
 Group By productline,orderdate
```